# MatLab/Simulink TCP/Receive getting bad data

Tags: java, matlab, sockets, tcp, simulink

I have Java code sending TCP/IP data to Matlab that works using the following code:

```
four=tcpip('localhost', 4444, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
set(four,'Timeout', 30);
set(four, 'InputBufferSize', 7688);
fopen(four);
fread(four,1,'double')
ans = 4.4
```

This all works as expected.  When I run the same Java code sending to a Simulink Instrument Control Toolbok TCP/IP Receive hooked up to a scope, it seems to only receive data when I have a Data type of single, but the value of the data is 2.275.

```
 Block {
  BlockType               Reference
  Name                    "Data From Java"
  SID                     "1"
  Ports                   [0, 1]
  Position                [120, 246, 230, 294]
  ZOrder                  2
  LibraryVersion          "1.84"
  SourceBlock             "instrumentlib/TCP//IP Receive"
  SourceType              "TCP/IP Receive"
  Host                    "127.0.0.1"
  Port                    "4444"
  DataSize                "[1 1]"
  EnableBlockingMode      on
  Timeout                 "30"
  SampleTime              "0.01"
  DataType                "single"
  ByteOrder               "BigEndian"
}
```

How do I read a binary double (float) into my Simulink model?

Comment: Could you please delete this.   It was a user error.  (My scope was displaying incorrectly)

Comment: there is a delete button under the question, you can delete by yourself.